# Filemaker summaries on related fields and calculations

Tags: filemaker

Attempting to create a calculation field for a sub-summary sorted on a related field

```
GetSummary ( sumValue ; client::grouping )
```

returns empty result.  Ordering and Summaries are being generated, but not the calculation.

I've attempted to create in the exiting table both a text field => lookup for `client::grouping`  and a calculation field `= client::grouping` as a sorting field and adjusting the breakField under getSummary, but am getting the same blank.

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The breakfield in GetSummary() must be a local field. A calculation field = `client::grouping` should serve well - but you also must sort by the same calculation field (and not by the related client::grouping field).

Comment: Had tried that.  In case anyone hits the problem: The problem I had was the `calculation was occurring on a text field which sort of trips itself up when handling spaces and such`. so I re-cast my origin with a unique serial ID and all flows well. Thanks for the confirmation anyway.

Comment: I don't see why having the calculation "occur on" (reference?) a text field would cause it to return a blank result. Sorting by a text field is sorting;  even if the resulting sort order might not be what you expect, the records are still sorted and GetSummary() is supposed to return a result.

Comment: the summary was fine up to a point. When the value of the break field had multiple reference in the source table, the sort would get confused, dish out data based on its internal rule (if any?) and the getSummary could not function from that point on.  The unique ID solves it.

Comment: I am glad you solved your problem - though I still have no idea what it was.

Comment: For completeness sake... Assume origin table with fields co_name, group_name and records: `[company A Ltd., company_A], [Company A LLB, company_A], [organisation B Ltd., Org_B]`.  The first two are part of the same group. Creating a calculation on group_name fails.  Creating a numeric serial, the problem is resolved.  I hypothesize the blame is on the handling of the space character.

Comment: LOL, this is just getting curiouser and curiouser... I suggest you either let it go or edit your question and provide a detailed step-by-step on how to reproduce the problem. At this point, I don't know what "a calculation on group_name" means, nor how it "fails". And there are no space characters in group_name.